# data reloading in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gnustep

simple existentialist question that google can't answer me:

When and NSOutlineView send the message outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem: to its data source, will it always reload its data?

I have [sourceList reloadData]; as the last line of that method's implementation, but it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary because it already has the new (user-entered) data for that row—if it didn't, it wouldn't be able to give it to you by sending you that message.

Comment: but it still waits for confirmation before displaying it, right? If you don't write the method, the text the user entered wont show

Comment: The method doesn't return a confirmation; it returns `void`. The outline view may ask for the same column of the same row afterward (in case you substituted a different object instead of using the one it gave you), but it does not need to reload the full data.